# Is it possible to use PouchDB's SQLite adapter in Chrome Apps?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome-app, pouchdb, nosql

I'm working on an offline first app and I was wondering if it possible to use PouchDB's SQLite adapter in a Chrome App?

For Cordova/PhoneGap the documentation shows:

https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html

```
var db = new PouchDB('myDB', {adapter: 'websql'});
```

Could this or something similar be used in Chrome Apps? I have successfully done some CRUD operations with the native IndexedDB. I'm really not trying to complicate things but this is just a question for those who prefer relational databases to nosql.

Comment: WebSQL is [not supported for apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps), so I guess it's a no.

Comment: That's what I believe I read some time back as well, thanks @wOxxOm